# Meteor and Flexbox : pagination slow loading results in flickering

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, meteor

Going back to the previous thumbnail overview results in flickering. Looking at it in slow motion the build up of the thumbnail page becomes visible. If the images are loaded fast, the problem disappears, but is very visible if the connection is slow. Is there a way keep the thumbnail page in cache or render the page after flexbox places all the elements? Or is there any other solution? Thanks!

Slow motion:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3vvCRIJdRo

All images are small sprites that are then drawn to canvases btw. I'm also using flexbox.

Website: http://eboydb.mod.bz/pool/all/1 (will remove this link – if fixed)

**Edit:**

Just tried to use waitOn with Iron Router – as suggested below. It doesn't seem to make a difference though.

```
Router.route('/pool/:slug/:page', {
    name: 'pool',
    template: 'pool',
    after: function() {
        document.title = siteName + ' /pool/' + this.params.slug + '/' + this.params.page;
    },
    waitOn: function() {
        // set search slugs that will show everything
        var allOptions = [
            "all",
            "everything",
            "show all",
        ];
        // when the slug is part of the array show everything
        if (allOptions.indexOf(this.params.slug.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
            var searchTerm = ".*";
            // console.log('slug: all > ' + this.params.slug);
        } else {
            var searchTerm = this.params.slug;
        }
        Meteor.subscribe('PixQuery', searchTerm, this.params.page);
    },
    data: function() {
        templateData = {
            slug: this.params.slug,
        }
        return templateData;
    }
});
```

Comment: way easier solution : put the full size image in a modal, even if it covers the whole screen, and don't change the route to view the full size image.  just open and close a modal.

Comment: Thanks @looshi – actually a modal could be a nice approach! Problem is I'd like to be able to share the link to a specific asset. Thinking about it it might be an option to add a permalink for those cases. I'm also not sure about the implications as I hope to be able to implement Twitter Cards https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview – and maybe Facebook Open Graph https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph

Comment: Tried to implement a modal but there seems to be a problem with iron router. Nothing happens when going to `/pool/all/1#openModal`. As if iron router is ignoring it.

Comment: Alternatively I'm not sure how to display the placeholder box – before loading the images.

Comment: try this for your router setup : https://gist.github.com/looshi/14d64f98e07c1068f936

Comment: Cool! :) ... but I'm not sure I understand the suggestion correctly. I do have a route for a single view already: http://eboydb.mod.bz/spriteBox/5C5PLhHy8qYRerj8X/512 – maybe not as well organized (no custom RouteController), but it's working fine. The problem are the slow loading images when the viewer goes back to the thumbnail page – not the missing single image view. Or that I didn't manage to set up a modal that works with iron router. The project is on GitHub btw: https://github.com/c6y/eboydb

Comment: i see.  it could be due to a number of factors, it's hard to tell right now.  if you want more help, open an issue on github and assign it to me - @looshi , i'll check it out.  that's a cool project you're working on.  would it be possible to extend that idea out to animated pixel art ?

Comment: Thanks a lot @looshi! Will get back to you if I don't get it solved. And yes animation would be wonderful to have! It's definitely on the todo-list. If you have any ideas how to contribute just let me know. Or you can always fork the project. :)